# Does Mono generates the same GUI/results/behavior when running the same application on Windows Mono and Linux Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono

I need to develop Coded UI automation tests on Windows and on Linux OS using Mono for a huge C# Win-Form application.

Since I couldn't find such tool that enables automation of C# application on Linux with Mono I would like to know if I'll will install Mono on Windows and run my application on it I'll get the same results/behavior as when I'll run it on Linux with Mono? can anyone please assist?

Comment: `...get the same results/behavior...` No, due to the fact that GUI drivers are different on Linux/macOS, you can expect "differences" on different platforms, what those are depends greatly upon your application (i.e. COM/ActiveX widgets of course do not exist, differences in widget sizing, wildly varying performance, etc...)  (Mono-based WinForms has been archived/obsoleted mode for some time now)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for clarifying this issue :-)